Smoothing projective nodal curve, is the general fiber smooth?
Proposition 29.9 of Hartshorne's Deformation theory states the following:
A reduced curve Y in $\mathbb{P}^n$ with locally smoothable singularities and $H^1(Y,O_Y(1)) = 0$ is smoothable. In particular, this applies if Y has locally complete intersection singularities.
Hartshorne says on page 200 that smoothable means there exists a flat family $\chi \subseteq \mathbb{P}^n_T$ over an integral scheme of finite type $T$ where $Y$ is some fiber of $\chi$, and there are smooth fibers of $\chi$.
My question is the following: Hartshorne makes no mention of whether, in the case of a nodal curve, whether a general fiber is smooth? Is this true though? Or are there examples where the family which demonstrates "smooth ability" of a nodal curve has general fiber which remains singular.

I’m not sure I understand what exactly you are asking. Is your question whether every nodal curve is smoothable?

No, we know by Hartshorne's proposition that every nodal curve (with H^1 vanishing) is smoothable. Im asking whether it can be exhibited to be smoothable in a flat family where the general fiber is also smooth. Maybe I'm confused, but Hartshorne seems to only say existence of smooth fiber.

Oh, I see. Doesn’t this follow from the fact that the smooth locus is open?

Sorry if this is a stupid question but can you give a reference of this fact / can you state this fact in more generality with the necessary hypotheses? Would be really helpful to me, thanks.

Let $f:X \to T$ be a flat and proper morphism, locally of finite presentation. By Tag 01V8, $f$ is smooth if and only if the fibers of $f$ are smooth. The set of points in $X$ where $f$ is not smooth is closed (it's the support of the cokernel of $f^*\Omega_T \to \Omega_X$), call it $Z$. Then $f(Z)$ is closed since $f$ is proper. Let $U = T\setminus f(Z)$. $U$ is open and by the first fact it is the set of points $t \in T$ such that $X_t$ is smooth.
If $T$ is integral, then as soon as there is a single smooth fiber, $U$ is nonempty and thus dense.
